# UINavigationBar font replication

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to create a custom share button to implement into my xcode project instead of just typing in the word "share" into the bar item's title in the attributes inspector. I am creating a small image instead with a little image followed by the word "share." Since I am creating the image on my PC I want to replicate or come close to the default "item" button font:

[image]

Does anyone know the default font used on iphones? And what size i should make the image to be around the same size as the button in the image?

Thanks

Comment: You can use a custom `UIView` inside a `UIBarButtonItem` so you can use any view that you want. In your case I'd use a `UIButton` with the text and icon instead of a new image with the text. Try to avoid adding texts to images as it makes much more difficult to internationalize the application and the user cannot change the font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helvetica-Neue and soon San Francisco with IOS 9

See more here:

http://iosfonts.com/